# Entity Framework 4.1 - Error in many-to-many relationship data when insert data that removed previously

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, many-to-many, ef-code-first

The scenarios:

3 tables I have which form a Many-to-many relationship:

```
Agent (AgentID (PK), AgentName)
AgentChannel (AgentID (PK), ChannelID (PK))
Channel (ChannelID (PK), ChannelName)
```

I do not want to add/delete any record in Agent and Channel tables, but only modify the AgentChannel table.

I am using EF 4.1, POCO and Self-Tracking Entity. All codes that deal with database are include in WCF layer which I calls them server side code, and I only able to control the add/remove of records in client side code.

For example:
I has one Agent record, with multiple Channel records. I able to link existing channel to agent in this way:

```
var channel = new Channel { ChannelID = 1 };
channel.MarkAsUnchanged();
agent.Channels.Add(channel);
// This will add new entry to AgentChannel table, but no change on Agent and Channel tables
```

Also I can remove the linkage of a channel to agent in this way:

```
var tempChannels = agent.Channels.ToList();
var channelToDelete = tempChannels.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ChannelID == 3);
agent.Channels.Remove(channelToDelete);
// This will remove the entry in AgentChannel, but no change on Agent and Channel tables.
```

**My problem:**
If I removed a channel, and add back a new channel which has the same ChannelID with the previously removed channel into agent.Channels collection , I will get this error:

> AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object’s key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager.

Sample code to demostrates:

```
        //
        // I not able to call ObjectContext here because it was reside in server side.
        //

        //
        // This is client side code
        //
        var tempChannels = agent.Channels.ToList();
        var channelToDelete = tempChannels.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ChannelID == 3);

        // remove channel 3
        agent.Channels.Remove(channelToDelete);

        var channel = new Channel { ChannelID = 3 };
        channel.MarkAsUnchanged();

        // Add back channel 3
        agent.Channels.Add(channel);

        //
        // This is server side code (WCF layer)
        //
        try
        {
            using (var ctx = new testEntities())
            {
                ctx.ApplyChanges("Agents", agent); // <-- ERROR happen here
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

then I got thie exception message:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.FixupKey(EntityEntry entry)
       at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.AcceptChanges()
       at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.ChangeObjectState(EntityState requestedState)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(Object entity, EntityState entityState)
       at TestManyToMany.SelfTrackingEntitiesContextExtensions.ChangeEntityStateBasedOnObjectState(ObjectContext context, IObjectWithChangeTracker entity) in F:\MyFile\Development\Temp\TestManyToMany\TestManyToMany\Model1.Context.Extensions.cs:line 728
       at TestManyToMany.SelfTrackingEntitiesContextExtensions.HandleEntity(ObjectContext context, EntityIndex entityIndex, RelationshipSet allRelationships, IObjectWithChangeTracker entity) in F:\MyFile\Development\Temp\TestManyToMany\TestManyToMany\Model1.Context.Extensions.cs:line 596
       at TestManyToMany.SelfTrackingEntitiesContextExtensions.ApplyChanges[TEntity](ObjectContext context, String entitySetName, TEntity entity) in F:\MyFile\Development\Temp\TestManyToMany\TestManyToMany\Model1.Context.Extensions.cs:line 84
       at TestManyToMany.Program.Main(String[] args) in F:\MyFile\Development\Temp\TestManyToMany\TestManyToMany\Program.cs:line 53
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I hope I make myself clear. This is the only problem I facing now and I run out of idea.

Many thanks.

-

---

-

**Update - Answer**

I got the answer after done the testing according to comment from Ladislav Mrnka.

Basically you need to add back to the same entity which removed previously, no other entity because that will gave you the same error above.

Here is the sample code on client side, no changes required in server side:

```
        int channelId = 1;

        var tempChannels = agent.Channels.ToList();
        var channelToDelete = tempChannels.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ChannelID == channelId);

        // remove channel 1
        agent.Channels.Remove(channelToDelete);


        //var channel = _allChannels.First(c => c.ChannelID == channelId);
        //agent.Channels.Add(channel);           <-- This line will give you ERROR because the channel entity is from _allChannels, but not from agent.Channels

        // Add back channel 1
        agent.Channels.Add(channelToDelete); //  <-- This is CORRECT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not allowed operation. If you removed channel and you want to add it again you mustn't create a new instance. You must use the old one and only change its state. The main rule is that each entity with unique key must be declared only once. Your code results in two instances with the same key = error.

Comment: Thank you and It work now!! I think I miss out the testing on the entity which come from the parent entity!! I will update my finding in my question. Thanks again !